# What does this instruction mean?

Tags: c#

I'm using cefsharp to build a personal browser.
Everything is fine but i've got a question for you.

What does this instruction mean? It is inserted in the main form.
`this.InvokeOnUiThreadIfRequired(() => urlTextBox.Text = browser.Address);`

In the project i have also a Control static class which implements InvokeOnUiThreadIfRequired function.

```
public static void InvokeOnUiThreadIfRequired(this Control control, Action action)
{
    if (control.InvokeRequired)
    {
        control.BeginInvoke(action);
    }
    else
    {
        action.Invoke();
    }
}
```

So the questions are:
- What does the form pass to the function? I don't understand the meaning of `() =>`.
- What does the function receive as parameters?

Comment: This method is an extension method You can call on any Control class instance. The syntax provided is just a short lambda expression to pass a the action You want to be made(omitting control attribute)

Comment: `() => { /* statements here */ }` is an anonymous delegate. It has the type `Action`. It is the equivalent of `void Method() { }` (without the name).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There a three interesting parts:

1. `InvokeOnUiThreadIfRequired`: This code probably checks if the caller is on the UI thread. Since you are not allowed to change the UI from another thread than thr UI thread, this code is necessary.
2. `() =>` is a lambda expression following with the anonymous delegate (projected on an `Action` which is effectively a method with no parameters and no return value) to execute. In that way you can pass on a call to some code to another method.
3. The `InvokeOnUiThreadIfRequired` method is an [extension method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/bb383977.aspx). It allows you to 'attach' a method to an instance of another type which you don't own as it was a method of that class.

Comment: Thanks Patrick for the explanation. Another question:
what about 'this Control control' in parameters declaration?

Comment: Please see the link on extension methods: it is the instance the extension method is showed on.